# Error with WindowName.Show()

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a problem with some vb code.
I am trying to make a button on one page open a user control using `WINDOWNAME.Show()`

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub PowerToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PowerToolStripMenuItem.Click
  PowerCtrl.Show()
End Sub
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> Error 1
>   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
>   C:\Users\Alpha\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Home.vb 9   9   WindowsApplication1

I am happy to give more code.

Comment: What is `PowerCtrl` and where is it declared? If it's a normal form then it should work...

Comment: Thanks but I fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to make your 'User Control' form in to a normal form**

Comment: Oh it was a `UserControl`. Then it's not even a form, just a control that can be added to a form. :)